# Achieve multiple components in a dashboard home page using CSS grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid, dashboard

I am new to CSS Grid Layout.

---

Problems I am facing while trying to achieve following using css grids
[image]

1. Unable to achieve responsive design. (Responsiveness doesn't go well with different screen size ratios. Example 4:3 or 16:9)
2. It is well known most of things doesn't go well when testing the application in Internet Explorer (Here I am talking about IE11)
   **(Edit: Excluded, until IE supports CSS grid layout)**
3. It is a web tool dashboard, scroll bar should not appear in any condition while using in a full screen view.
4. Restricted to use third party plug-in or poly-fills. (Because of commercial use)
5. Restricted to use negative values in css properties.

---

(Edit: I know it can be achieved using media queries plus other CSS layout properties. Here I am trying to achieve this with minimal and cleaner code). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you use relative units it will resize according to your screen size. For different layouts you still need [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
2. [CSS-grid is not fully supported by IE11.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) That usually isn't a problem as you should use a mobile-first approach anyways and mobile websites [usually don't look bad on desktop anyways](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)
3. There is nothing special about the grid layout here. (If anything, it makes it easier: media queries + absolute units = magic) Either use media queries or `overflow: hidden;`
4. *Restricted to use third party plug-in or poly-fills.* Ähm no? I don't understand what you mean
5. *Restricted to use negative values in css properties.* Again, no, you're generally not? What's the problem here?

Comment: YES. You can't just answer nope. CSS-grid won't be able to solve problems it doesn't even affect. If you want responsive design, you need relative units and media queries. (which are a clean way if done correctly) CSS-grid is a tool for layouting, so why do you think, it should solve other problems. That is like asking HTML to add two numbers together.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I watched alot of mis-leading tutorials on YouTube which interprets as CSS grid layout is a all in one solution to responsive design. Thanks

Comment: I had a hard time achieving the layout presented in the image (mentioned in question). I was looking for better approach, and I asked this question by assuming CSS grid layout could help me in achieving it.

Comment: It can, but you cannot achieve all the things you mentioned purely with css-grid. You can make that layout, but still use 'older' tech for other problems. (e.g. use css-grid ALONGSIDE flexbox, not instead

Comment: Okay. So many down votes, it makes my question feel dumb. Web spec implementation across all the web clients screwed up. So CSS Unicorn(perfect) layout doesn't exist.